# Using PJSIP open source library for VoIP media and signal handling

Tags: android, server, voip, pjsip

I am fairly new to android, I got a job as a Junior Android and I've been suggested to use PJSIP to create the back-end functionality of a VoIP app. It's meant to be handling the media transfer and singaling on its own.

I'm struggling while going through the documentation. I try to read it but it's hard trying to understand the code and functions. How do I implement a library written in C, in Android Studio (Java)? How do I read through the documentation and understand what I'm meant to do?

I've tried reading through the PJSIP Developer's Guide, most of it seems incomprehensible to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am developing a similar application to yours along with video support. I am yet to integrate the pjsip library to the app. But have built the library for android.

To answer your questions,
NDK(an SDK available in android studio) is used to implement native languages such as C and C++ in android. Using JNI interface the C,C++ code is made compatible with android, You don't have hard code any of these for now.
Go to pjsip and get tar or zip files based on the platform(either windows or linux) and extract it into your system.
You also need to install ndk, google through the steps.

Building the library would be a bit of hassle. So follow the official guide and for the errors that arise follow the steps below

Buiding PJSIP for android
Go to the directory of the pjproject downloaded for android

Go pjproject/pjlib/include/pj and check for config_site.h file, if not found create one and add : 
hashtag define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1
hashtag include angular braces pj/config_site_sample.h angular braces

export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = path to the ndk-bundle of ndk(downloaded).

Go to the root folder of pjproject and 
execute 
./configure
 make dep && make clean && make

Errors:

For no compiler found error install clang using sudo apt-get clang
and execute 
export CC="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain $NDK_TOOLCHAIN"
export CXX="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain $NDK_TOOLCHAIN"

For C compiler cannot create executables error
Grant permission to ndk-bundle

chmod -R 777 ndk-bundle

For missing seperator error in any folders 
execute find . -type f -name '*.depend' | xargs rm

For any other errors, also install g++

Answer (score 1):

Find pjsua example application for android in pjsip-apps. It has good example of how pjsip c-library is used via JNI interface from android java application.